# why my application use all memory and get OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

why this happeing all the time?i dont have even a bitmap to recycle and i dont know why my application throw memory error.

i select image from gallery here is the code to get an image from gallery then show it on some imageView.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ImageView b = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                b.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
            b.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            b.setTag(picturePath);

        }
    }
}
```

after that there is 3 imagebuttons below user image(which picked from gallery). when user press on each one of them will get the name of that imageView drawable and will send to another activity then i want to watermark user image on that Imagebutton and show in one imageView

```
private static HashMap<Integer,String> activityMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
static {
    activityMap.put( R.id.agahi1,"agahi1");
    activityMap.put( R.id.agahi2,"agahi2");
}
// use this in the layout xml file for all the buttons onClick attribute
public void Clicked( View vw ) {
    String a = String.valueOf(activityMap.get(vw.getId()));

    Intent i = new Intent(this,fotCreator.class);

    ImageView b = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.viewImage);

    String c = (String) b.getTag();

    i.putExtra("image",c);
    i.putExtra("frame",a);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

this is the code for watermarker activity

```
    package net.svncorp.shadikade;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class fotCreator extends ActionBarActivity {
    private AsyncCaller myasync;
    private ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fot_creator);
        //progress bar
        bar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        MainActivity.checkversion(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myasync = new AsyncCaller();
        myasync.execute();

    }

    private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>
    {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {            // simulate here the slow activity
                Intent intent = getIntent();

                final String frame = intent.getStringExtra("frame");
                String image = intent.getStringExtra("image");
                Resources resources = getResources();
                int id = resources.getIdentifier(frame, "drawable", getPackageName());
                Drawable d = resources.getDrawable(id);
                return d;


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            ImageView finalimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.finalimage);
            if (isCancelled() || result == null) {
                return;
            }
            finalimage.setImageDrawable(result);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }



    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myasync.cancel(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fot_creator, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

now this code works so fast for 2 or 3 times of pressing imagebuttons and go to watermarker activty but its keep getting slower and slower and sometimes it freeze in emulator and i see these in logcat

```
 11-24 15:01:45.960    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2419(163KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(1047KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 13MB/15MB, paused 0 total 30ms
11-24 15:01:48.760    7751-7768/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 17MB to 16MB
11-24 15:01:48.760    7751-7768/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 17MB to 16MB
11-24 15:01:48.760    7751-7768/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1047KB allocation
11-24 15:01:48.790    7751-7768/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1303(86KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(993KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 13MB/15MB, paused 0 total 30ms
11-24 15:01:53.700    7751-7751/net.svncorp.shadikade I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 1272 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-24 15:01:55.350    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 17MB to 16MB
11-24 15:01:55.350    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 17MB to 16MB
11-24 15:01:55.350    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 993KB allocation
11-24 15:01:55.380    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 17MB to 16MB
11-24 15:01:55.380    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 218(9KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 15MB/16MB, paused 0 total 30ms
11-24 15:01:55.380    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1017612 byte allocation with 954752 free bytes and 932KB until OOM"
11-24 15:01:55.380    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false
11-24 15:01:55.380    7751-7769/net.svncorp.shadikade E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: net.svncorp.shadikade, PID: 7751
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1017612 byte allocation with 954752 free bytes and 932KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:758)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:724)
            at net.svncorp.shadikade.fotCreator$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(fotCreator.java:65)
            at net.svncorp.shadikade.fotCreator$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(fotCreator.java:45)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

i think this is the problem of many others like me... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see your setting an Imageview bitmap then resizing the same bitmap.  Perhaps give the imageview a simple copy of the bitmap.

Answer (score 44):

Maybe  adding this line in Manifest on application tags will help you;

```
<application
        ...
        ...
        android:largeHeap="true" >  

     ......
     ......

</application>
```

Comment: @Cüneyt I know this was about 2 years back but for anyone coming back to this response from a search engine, I down-voted since using `android:largeHeap="true"` should be a last option.

Comment: @AnilGorthy Thank you for your advice. If you can write other options we can fix the answer.

Comment: before set largeHeap read this post: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/leakcanary-detect-all-memory-leaks-875ff8360745#.lccgfnif5

Answer (score 15):

Had similar issue on Android 5. Move your images to /drawable-nodpi instead of /drawable

Comment: Why? Could you explaim please?

Comment: @Ton if you put your images to /drawable-nodpi, android will retain its size.

Comment: I think it has something to do with automatic scaling of image using current device DPI. Images from /drawable-nodpi are not scaled.

Comment: For example if you have big image in /drawable-mdpi, but your device is xxxhdpi, then Android takes the image available in mdpi and tries to scale it up to match xxxhdpi, which can occupy too much memory. But images from /drawable-nodpi are not scaled, they are used as they are.

Comment: Yup! That's all it took!

Answer (score 6):

If your are using Emulator for testing Try setting the Ram of virtual Device to 2gb or so.
i had the same problem on Virtual Device but the program Run smooth on my physical android device