# java out of memory exception on setting multiple images on GridView using baseadapter

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-gridview, baseadapter

When I try to scroll images with atleast 50 images, the application crashes.

"Failed to allocate a 841692 byte allocation with 233120 free bytes and 227KB until OOM"

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sstechnology.com.sssticks, PID: 24617
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 841692 byte allocation with 233120 free bytes and 227KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613) 
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2813)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2514)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2416)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:800)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:747)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:398)
at sstechnology.com.jiprasticks.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:59)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
```

I am trying to set images to gridView which is in a fragment with tab layout. There are 10 tabs in which each of them has same layout file but with different images in gridView.

Here is the code for a single fragment.

```
 int[] pics={...}; // i am declaring R.drawable.name implicitly
    public ExpressionStickerFragment(Context context, int size)
{

    this.size = size;
    this.context=context;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sticker_fragment,container,false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context,pics,size));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ShareClass shareClass=new ShareClass(context);
        //   System.out.println("=== "+position);
            shareClass.createPreview(pics[position],0);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

And here is the ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
int[] images;
int imageSize;
int h=0;
public ImageAdapter(Context context,int[] images ,int imageSize)
{
    this.imageSize=imageSize;
    this.context=context;
    this.images=images;

}

public ImageAdapter(Context context,int[] images ,int imageSize,int imageHeight)
{
    this.imageSize=imageSize;
    this.context=context;
    this.images=images;
     h=imageHeight;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    try {


        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        if(h==0)


        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageSize, imageSize));
        else
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageSize, h));



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error ==== " +e);
    }

    return imageView;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your images may be too big.

Comment: no <=60kb atleast 50 images in each fragment and there are 10 tabs

Comment: I meant too big for the amount of memory you had left. Have you tried [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115944/why-my-application-use-all-memory-and-get-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate) solutions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I myself solved it using largeHeap in the manifest